# why JMHSample_12_Forking fork0 is fater then fork1?

Tags: java, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I'm reading the JMH sample.

Why the  `measure_1_c1()` is faster 
than  `measure_4_forked_c1()` OR `measure_5_forked_c2()`

[Find code here](https://github.com/victorsheng/benchmark-anything/blob/master/jmh-source/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_12_Forking.java)

```
    @Benchmark
    @Fork(0)
    public int measure_1_c1() {
        return measure(c1);
    }


    @Benchmark
    @Fork(1)
    public int measure_4_forked_c1() {
        return measure(c1);
    }
```

Logs [Result here](http://%20https://github.com/victorsheng/benchmark-anything/blob/master/jmh-source/jmh-samples/logs/JMHSample_12_Forking.log)

```
Benchmark                                 Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
JMHSample_12_Forking.measure_1_c1         avgt    5   3.940 ± 0.097  ns/op
JMHSample_12_Forking.measure_2_c2         avgt    5  28.298 ± 0.253  ns/op
JMHSample_12_Forking.measure_3_c1_again   avgt    5  27.643 ± 0.702  ns/op
JMHSample_12_Forking.measure_4_forked_c1  avgt    5   5.974 ± 0.618  ns/op
JMHSample_12_Forking.measure_5_forked_c2  avgt    5   5.734 ± 0.838  ns/op
```